# How to Add column heading to default action in Active admin rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to add column name to default actions in rails active admin gem. By default column name is empty.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 actions name: "Actions"
```